# Generate random number in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm trying to generate a random number in my simple app but this error comes can anyone please help me with this.

> ./src/ComLifeCycle.js
>
> Syntax error: E:/REACT/props-states/src/ComLifeCycle.js: Unexpected
>   token, expected, (31:37)
>
> > 31 |     this.setState(number: Math.random()); // problem in this line.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './ComLifeCycle.css';

class ComLifeCycle extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <Body />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Body extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
    this.generateRandomNumber = this.generateRandomNumber.bind(this);
  }

  generateRandomNumber = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    this.setState(number: Math.random()); // **problem in this line**
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <button onClick={this.generateRandomNumber}>Random number</button>
        <Number myNumber={this.state.number}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Number extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <br />
        <p>{this.props.myNumber}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComLifeCycle;
```

Comment: you're missing the curly braces in your `setState()` call, it should be `this.setState({number: Math.random()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of this.setState is wrong. Here is the correct syntax

`this.setState({number: Math.random()});`

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for `setState` is **incorrect**, it needs the updated values to be an object. In short you are missing curly braces around `number: Math.random()`

```
this.setState({number: Math.random()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass object instead of props, Try this

```
this.setState({number: Math.random()});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `setState` syntax is wrong you are missing `{}` braces there so do it this way :

```
 generateRandomNumber = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.random()
    this.setState({number : randomNumber})); 
  }
```